# Python If statement not being exectuted allthough true

Tags: python, if-statement, bitcoin

I am writing a bit of code which calls an API to get the latest Bitcoin Block Hash value. I convert the hash into decimal and then wish to take the first two digits and add them to a list providing they are of small enough size. I have added an if else statement which you can see to be true however it is never executed, I have no idea why. I am relatively new to python so go easy on me.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import blocktrail, time, csv, sys
class Bit():
    def __init__(self, key, secret, net, retry_fail=1, update=10,max_fail=10):
        self.hash_list = []
        self.seen = set()
        self.key = "x"
        self.secret = "x"
        self.net = "BTC"
        self.key = key
        self.retry_fail = retry_fail
        self.update = update
        self.max_fails = max_fail

def connect(self):
    return blocktrail.APIClient(api_key="x", api_secret="x", network="BTC", testnet=False)
    address = client.address('x')

def run(self):
    while True:
        if not self.max_fails:
            break
        try:
            client = self.connect()
            latest_block = client.block_latest()

        except blocktrail.exceptions.MissingEndpoint as e:
            self.max_fails -= 1
            print("Error: {}\n sleeping for {} second(s) before retrying".format(e.msg, self.retry_fail))
            time.sleep(self.retry_fail)
            continue
        hashc = latest_block['hash']

        hashcdec = int(hashc, 16)
        strhashcdec = str(hashcdec)
        hashcdecn = strhashcdec[0:2]

        print(hashcdec)

        while True:
            if hashcdecn < 100:
                self.hash_list.append(hashcdecn)
                self.seen.add(hashcdecn)
                print(self.hash_list)

            else:
                print(hashcdecn)
                print("number is too big")
                sys.exit()


        else:
            time.sleep(self.update)

Bit("key","secret","net").run()
```

Comment: I can see two `if`s here. Which one do you mean?

Comment: There are two `if` statements in here. How do you know the `if` expression is supposed to be true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing a *string* with an integer:

```
strhashcdec = str(hashcdec)
hashcdecn = strhashcdec[0:2]

# ....

if hashcdecn < 100:
```

Integers always sort before strings in Python 2, so no matter what the value of `hashcdecn`, it'll always test as *larger* than an integer. Convert your number back to an integer first:

```
if int(hashcdecn) < 100:
```

or better still, don't use a string in the first place:

```
hashcdec = int(hashc, 16)
hashcdecn = hashcdc % 100
```

Note that *either number* will **always** be smaller than 100, since you are grabbing just 2 digits here.

Comment: Yes it was just for testing purposes at the moment to see if the code would run how I want.